# Why am I getting a NullPointerException when trying to read a file?

Tags: java, file-io, itext

I use this test to convert txt to pdf :

```
package convert.pdf;

//getResourceAsStream(String name) : Returns an input stream for reading the specified resource.
//toByteArray : Get the contents of an InputStream as a byte[].

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import convert.pdf.txt.TextConversion;

public class TestConversion {

  private static byte[] readFilesInBytes(String file) throws IOException {
      return IOUtils.toByteArray(TestConversion.class.getResourceAsStream(file));
  }

  private static void writeFilesInBytes(byte[] file, String name) throws IOException {
      IOUtils.write(file, new FileOutputStream(name));
  }

  //just change the extensions and test conversions
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
      ConversionToPDF algorithm = new TextConversion();
      byte[] file = readFilesInBytes("/convert/pdf/text.txt");
      byte[] pdf = algorithm.convertDocument(file);
      writeFilesInBytes(pdf, "text.pdf");
  }

}
```

Problem:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copyLarge(IOUtils.java:1025)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.copy(IOUtils.java:999)
    at org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.toByteArray(IOUtils.java:218)
    at convert.pdf.TestConversion.readFilesInBytes(TestConversion.java:17)
    at convert.pdf.TestConversion.main(TestConversion.java:28)
```

I use the debugger, and the problem seems to be located here :

```
  private static byte[] readFilesInBytes(String file) throws IOException {
      return IOUtils.toByteArray(TestConversion.class.getResourceAsStream(file));
  }
```

What is my problem?

Answer (score 20):

Sounds like the resource probably doesn't exist with that name.

Are you aware that `Class.getResourceAsStream()` finds a resource relative to that class's package, whereas `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream()` doesn't? You can use a leading forward slash in `Class.getResourceAsStream()` to mimic this, so

```
Foo.class.getResourceAsStream("/bar.png")
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
Foo.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("bar.png")
```

Is this *actually* a file (i.e. a specific file on the normal file system) that you're trying to load? If so, using `FileInputStream` would be a better bet. Use `Class.getResourceAsStream()` if it's a resource bundled in a jar file or in the classpath in some other way; use `FileInputStream` if it's an arbitrary file which could be anywhere in the file system.

EDIT: Another thing to be careful of, which has caused me problems before now - if this has worked on your dev box which happens to be Windows, and is now failing on a production server which happens to be Unix, check the case of the filename. The fact that different file systems handle case-sensitivity differently can be a pain...

Answer (score 1):

Are you checking to see if the file exists before you pass it to `readFilesInBytes()`?  Note that `Class.getResourceAsStream()` returns `null` if the file cannot be found.  You probably want to do:

```
private static byte[] readFilesInBytes(String file) throws IOException {
  File testFile = new File(file);
  if (!testFile.exists()) {
      throw new FileNotFoundException("File " + file + " does not exist");
  }
  return IOUtils.toByteArray(TestConversion.class.getResourceAsStream(file));
}
```

or better yet:

```
private static byte[] readFilesInBytes(String file) throws IOException {
  InputStream stream = TestConversion.class.getResourceAsStream(file);
  if (stream == null) {
      throw new FileNotFoundException("readFilesInBytes: File " + file
                                      + " does not exist");
  }
  return IOUtils.toByteArray(stream);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This class reads a TXT file in the classpath and uses TextConversion to convert to PDF, then save the pdf in the file system.

Here TextConversion code :

```
package convert.pdf.txt;
//Conversion to PDF from text using iText.
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import convert.pdf.ConversionToPDF;
import convert.pdf.ConvertDocumentException;

import com.lowagie.text.Document;
import com.lowagie.text.DocumentException;
import com.lowagie.text.Font;
import com.lowagie.text.Paragraph;
import com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter;

public class TextConversion implements ConversionToPDF {

    public byte[] convertDocument(byte[] documents) throws ConvertDocumentException {
        try {
            return this.convertInternal(documents);
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            throw new ConvertDocumentException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ConvertDocumentException(e);
        }
    }

    private byte[] convertInternal(byte[] documents) throws DocumentException, IOException {
        Document document = new Document();

        ByteArrayOutputStream pdfResultBytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, pdfResultBytes);

        document.open();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( new ByteArrayInputStream(documents) ) );

        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            if ("".equals(line.trim())) {
                line = "\n"; //white line
            }
            Font fonteDefault = new Font(Font.COURIER, 10);
            Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(line, fonteDefault);
            document.add(paragraph);
        }

        reader.close();

        document.close();

        return pdfResultBytes.toByteArray();
    }
}
```

And here the code to ConversionToPDF :

```
package convert.pdf;
// Interface implemented by the conversion algorithms.
public interface ConversionToPDF {

    public byte[] convertDocument(byte[] documentToConvert) throws ConvertDocumentException;
    }
```

I think the problem come from my file system (devbox on windows and server is Unix).
I will try to modify my classpath.

Answer (score 0):

This problem may be caused by calling methods on `test.txt`, which can be a folder shortcut. In other words, you're calling a method on a file that doesn't exist, resulting in a `NullPointerException`.